# How to get specific type value from raw type Map in java

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have a raw type Map to store data because the data type could be different. Unfortunately it always returns value as Object type even we can get the exact type with getClass().

How to get specific type value from raw type Map?

```
/*
Expected result:
class java.lang.Boolean
func1(boolean p)
class java.lang.Integer
func1(int p)
class java.lang.Double
func1(double p)
class java.lang.Character
func1(char p)
class java.lang.String
func1(String p)
class java.lang.Object
func1(Object p)
class java.lang.Boolean
func1(boolean p)
class java.lang.Integer
func1(int p)
class java.lang.Double
func1(double p)
class java.lang.Character
func1(char p)
class java.lang.String
func1(String p)
class java.util.LinkedList
func1(List p)
class java.util.LinkedHashMap
func1(Map p)
class [Ljava.lang.Object;
func1(Object[] p)

Actual result:
class java.lang.Boolean
func1(Object p)
class java.lang.Integer
func1(Object p)
class java.lang.Double
func1(Object p)
class java.lang.Character
func1(Object p)
class java.lang.String
func1(Object p)
class java.lang.Object
func1(Object p)
class java.lang.Boolean
func1(Object p)
class java.lang.Integer
func1(Object p)
class java.lang.Double
func1(Object p)
class java.lang.Character
func1(Object p)
class java.lang.String
func1(Object p)
class java.util.LinkedList
func1(Object p)
class java.util.LinkedHashMap
func1(Object p)
class [Ljava.lang.Object;
func1(Object p)
*/

import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map map = init();

        for (Object v_obj : map.keySet()) {
            println(v_obj + ":\t" + map.get(v_obj).getClass());
            func1(map.get(v_obj));
        }
    }

    public static void func1(boolean p) {
        println("func1(boolean p)");
    }

    public static void func1(int p) {
        println("func1(int p)");
    }

    public static void func1(double p) {
        println("func1(double p)");
    }

    public static void func1(char p) {
        println("func1(char p)");
    }

    public static void func1(String p) {
        println("func1(String p)");
    }

    public static void func1(Object p) {
        println("func1(Object p)");
    }

    public static void func1(List p) {
        println("func1(List p)");
    }

    public static void func1(Map p) {
        println("func1(Map p)");
    }

    public static void func1(Object[] p) {
        println("func1(Object[] p)");
    }

    public static <T> void println(T p_t) {
        System.out.println(p_t);
    }

    public static Map init() {
        Map map = new LinkedHashMap();
        //map.put("null", null);
        map.put("boolean", true);
        map.put("int", 123);
        map.put("double", 123.456);
        map.put("char", 'c');
        map.put("string", "123asd'\"/\\");

        map.put("Object", new Object());
        map.put("Boolean", new Boolean(true));
        map.put("Integer", new Integer(123));
        map.put("Double", new Double(123.456));
        map.put("Character", new Character('c'));
        map.put("String", new String("123asd'\"/\\"));
        map.put("List", new LinkedList());
        map.put("Map", new LinkedHashMap());

        map.put("Object[]", new Object[]{});

        return map;
    }

}
```

Comment: Short of using reflections there's no way to do this.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to understand is that generics are a compile time concept. There's nothing dynamic (runtime) about them.

The next thing to understand is that methods are bound at compile time based on the parameter types and the type of the arguments provided. So which of

```
public static void func1(boolean p) {
    println("func1(boolean p)");
}

public static void func1(int p) {
    println("func1(int p)");
}
// and more
```

is bound depends on the actual type argument used in the invocation.  You're using

```
for (Object v_obj : map.values()) {
    println(v_obj.getClass());
    func1(v_obj.getClass().cast(v_obj));
}
```

So what does

```
v_obj.getClass().cast(v_obj)
```

return? The javadoc of [`Object#getClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--) states

> The actual result type is `Class<? extends |X|>` where `|X|` is the
>   erasure of the static type of the expression on which `getClass` is
>   called.

The expression on which `getClass` is called is `v_obj`, which is of type `Object`. So

```
v_obj.getClass()
```

returns a value of type `Class<? extends Object>`. The [`Class#cast(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast-java.lang.Object-) uses the type value bound to the type parameter `T` as its return value.  In this case that is also `Object`. So the method bound for an argument of type `Object` is the method with a parameter of type `Object`.